# prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{x}{|x|}$

Tags: calculus, limits

**Question**

How do I prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{x}{|x|}=-1$?

Because I thought that the answer would be DNE?

Comment: what are u trying to prove?

Comment: @JohnRawls Do you want to find $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{|x|}$? Also, are you looking for a place to start?

Comment: The limit doesn't exist but the left and right hand limits do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$\frac{x}{|x|}=\begin{cases}-1,\;\;x<0\\ \\+1,\;\;x>0\end{cases}$$

Also, $x\to 0^-$ is notation for $x$ converging to $0$ from the left.

Comment: How do I know that the top part of the piece wise function is true? I wanted a proof of this

Comment: What do you mean by "top part"?

Comment: @mzp write him the definition of absolute value and then simplify.

Comment: @JohnRawls If $x<0$, then $|x|=-x$, so $\frac x{|x|} = -1$. There isn't really anything to prove.

Comment: I understand your question now. @Math1000 has answered it.